# Spark Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop2

I'm a dummy on Ubuntu 16.04, desperately attempting to make Spark work.
I've tried to fix my problem using the answers found here on stackoverflow but I couldn't resolve anything.
Launching spark with the command `./spark-shell` from bin folder I get this message

```
WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable".
```

I'm using Java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_101
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode).
```

Spark is the latest version: 2.0.1 with Hadoop 2. 7. 
I've also retried with an older package of Spark, the 1.6.2 with Hadoop 2.4 but I get the same result. I also tried to install Spark on Windows but it seems harder than doing it on Ubuntu.

I also tried to run some commands on Spark from my laptop: I can define an object, I can create an RDD and store it in cache and I can use function like `.map()`, but when I try to run the function `.reduceByKey()` I receive several strings of error messages.

May be it's the Hadoop library which is compiled for 32bits, while I'm on 64bit?

Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't need to use the native-hadoop libraries -- that is just a warning indicating things will run more slowly.  It sounds like you have a different issue that is preventing you from doing a reduceByKey -- perhaps ask a different question with the resulting error messages you get

Answer (score 40):

Steps to fix:

- [download Hadoop binaries](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.3/hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz)
- unpack to directory of your choice
- set `HADOOP_HOME` to point to that directory.
- add `$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Go to /etc/profile.d directory and create a hadoop.sh file in there with

export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hadoop
export HIVE_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin
After you save the file, make sure to

chmod +x /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh
source /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow and made a mistake submitting the comment before time.
The thing I intended to do was to write the commands I should write to set HADOOP_HOME and add to LD_LIBRARY_PATH; so that You can correct me before doing damages.
So:
go to '/etc/profile.d directory' and create a **hadoop.sh** file in there with:
'export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hadoop'
'export HIVE_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hive'
'export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin'

After saving the file:
'chmod +x /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh
source /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh'.

Thank You so much for help!

Comment: It's best to use Spark config files for that by editing `conf/spark-env.sh` in your `SPARK_HOME`.

Comment: Tank Yo @LostInOverflow , so I should do:
`cd /spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf`
`sudo nano spark-env.sh`
and write inside it: `export HADOOP_HOME=/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.3`  then `export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native`  is it right? Sorry for redundant querying

Comment: If these are the paths.

Comment: @cane_mastino You don't need (and doing so has security risks) to set execution privileges on files under  /etc/profile.d . Those are "sourced" (the same way you do) from /etc/profile and then nobody should need to execute these files.

Comment: Why is this needed? Do we even need this to run Spark?

Answer (score 4):

1. Download hadoop binary ([link](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.0/hadoop-2.8.0.tar.gz)) and put it in your home directory
   (you can choose a different hadoop version if you like and change the next steps accordingly)
2. Unzip the folder in your home directory using the following command.
   tar -zxvf hadoop_file_name
3. Now add export HADOOP_HOME=~/hadoop-2.8.0 to your .bashrc file. Open a new terminal and try again.

Source: [Install PySpark on ubuntu](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-ubuntu-pyspark-231c45677de0)

Comment: You should not use .bashrc but the configuration file spark-env.sh for setting Spark's required environment variables.