# Unable to run scala test file due to installation problem with installation of java package

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

When I was running the Scala test code in IntelliJ, I was troubled by this error:

```
Testing started ...
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties
24/01/03 22:20:24 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.0
24/01/03 22:20:24 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
24/01/03 22:20:24 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
24/01/03 22:20:24 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
..
Exception in thread "globPath-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-57" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1218)
Process finished with exit code -1
```

Tried reinstalling packages, following these steps:

##### Java

- Download and extract "Java JDK (Zulu azure)" to `C:\Tools\zulu-8-azure-jdk\`
- Set system environment variable `%JAVA_HOME%` to `C:\Tools\zulu-8-azure-jdk`

##### Spark

- Download from above mentioned link and set up environment variable and path variable in system variables.

##### Environment variables

- `HADOOP_HOME`: `C:\\Tools\\Hadoop`
- `SPARK_HOME`: `C:\\Tools\\Spark`

##### `Path` variable containing

- `%Hadoop_Home%\\bin`
- `%SPARK_HOME%\\bin`

Comment: are you using Azure databricks?

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015416/spark-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform